# NGINX - rewrite rules for PHP REST

Tags: php, rest, api, nginx

I am currently learning REST with NGINX (and PHP-FPM).

I have a couple of questions around routing (e.g. /customers).

First of all should I be using NGINX or PHP for routing (put them as rewrite rules like `/customer/{cusID}` would map to `/customer.php?cusid={cusid})` or rewrite based on `/customer/{cusID}` mapping to `/customer.php` and then deal with if it has a `cusID` resource in the URI using PHP?

Second, is rewrite the best way of achieving this, I have seen that you can use alias in NGINX to do something similar?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would use a simple rewrite rule as follows:

```
rewrite ^customer/([0-9]+)$ /customer.php?cusid=$1 last
```

Your URL will be kept pretty-printed and you will be able to deal with the specified customer id within your PHP code.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, if I was using http method POST to create something against this customer e.g. /customer/543/address which would map to /address.php?cusid=543, is it ok to pull out the value for cusid from the query string in a post? e.g. first get the cusid from the query string using GET and then use this value in handling the post, or should the two GET/POST never be mixed together?

Comment: With POST query parameters things become a little bit harder... take a look at this question and it should provide you a good starting point: https://serverfault.com/questions/744021/nginx-rewrite-of-url-with-query-string

Comment: Thanks, yeah I see what its doing there, but I guess a more general question, is it ok to use query params in a post request as well as the post data? This isn't against any rules or standards?

Comment: Well if I was given the choice, I wouldn't use them. I prefer to use either query parameters OR post parameters without mixing. But since the framework allows you to do it, then it's legit.

Comment: Ok thanks, so based on that I am better to use the nginx to rewrite as above so everything goes to /customer.php and then use PHP to pull out the parts of the URI .e.g. /customer/543/address (so I would explode the URI based on forward slash and then use that value (543) in the code logic, thus removing the need for using query strings and post together?

Comment: Why don't you just use this then? rewrite ^customer/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)$ /customer.php?cusid=$1&action=$2 last

Comment: because I will need to then use post and get together then?

Comment: No buy you can handle multiple GET params in your PHP script isn't it?

Comment: Yeah I can handle multiple get but it’s when I need to post against a specific resource e.g. customer 543. So I have either 2 ways of doing this, both requires POSTing to a url that contains the customer id, but the first way it so rewrite to a query string and the other is to just parse the URI in the PHP script and get the customer id that way. The last way will not require me to $_GET[‘cusID’] during the post as I can just explode the SERVERs REQUEST_URI